# See chain of websites and domains being visited in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, website

I'm logging into to the Reading University student email (which uses Office Online) in Google Chrome. The initial login page address belongs to Reading University. After logging in, the address at the top of the browser goes through a bewildering (and rapid!) series of changes before finally settling on:

```
https://portal.office.com/Home
```

when you click on "Mail" you are taken to an `office.outlook.com` address.

Is there any way to see what websites and domains are flashing by from clicking "Log In" to finally reaching the inbox?

#### UPDATE

Using the Chrome DevTools (and other details supplied in the answers), I was able to find that the following domains were being visited (or objects like images, javascript, etc extracted from them). I selected all rows (CTRL+A), then right-click "Save as HAR with content", then opened the .har file in a text editor:

```
https://<READING-UNIVERSITY-EMAIL-WEB-ADDRESS>
https://login.microsoftonline.com/
https://portal.microsoftonline.com/
https://outlook.office365.com/
https://outlook.office.com/
https://portal.office.com/
https://prod.msocdn.com/
```

Wow...who knew? I find this a little disconcerting. As far as I am concerned, I am dealing with the University email only, but at least good to know. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: So, yes there is, but my question is why do you care?  All they're doing is going through a secure authentication protocol where your school can vouch for you to the `office.com` website.  This allows you to log into your account using your university credentials instead of a separate `office.com` account.

Comment: @heavyd: One example is if you are using a Chrome plugin such as ScriptBlock. While you can add an exception for the web addresses you know about, the ScriptBlock plugin shows its "Blocking!" icon on some of the addresses whizzing by. This can cause authentication problems (in my case, I have to go through the login process 3 times before I can finally see my inbox). This background information is useful, but not strictly relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built in Chrome Developers tools.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

By clicking the "network" tab before visiting the website, you'll be able to see all the requests the browser is making, including any redirects.

Keep in mind this will show all resources being pulled down as well. you'll likely be looking for status 301/302  which are the redirects.

Answer (score 3):

So, yes you can, but in order to do so you'll need to understand a little bit about HTTP and redirects.  The easiest way to do this, is to just use Chrome's built in developer tools.  You can access them from the menu under "More Tools" or by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Once in the tools, you'll want to flip over to the Network tab.  Then navigate to the login page for your email.  Click the clear button at the top of the network pane and check the box that says "Preservce log".  Now login and the first few entries in the network log will be all of the redirects that are happening.

Comment: On my version of Chrome the keyboard shortcut is `CTRL+SHIFT+I`, but same idea.

Answer (score 2):

Press F12, and then goto network tab, click on `preserve log`, and click on `doc` in the filter list.

### Animated Example:

[image]

### Updated

Read the comments about filtering by `doc`

Comment: Filtering by `doc` will hide redirects.  Redirects show up under `Other`.